# GRUB disabling timeout if PC reboots too often

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bootloader, grub

I have a multi-boot enabled system that has a few operating systems installed on it, and the booting of the actual OS is handled by GRUB initially. I have the following options in my boot menu:

```
[*] Ubuntu
    Win7
    Slackware
    MemTest86+
    GPartEd
```

Also, a 10 second timeout is in effect, so if I don't make a selection, it defaults to Ubuntu.

So, once in a while, I have to reboot and change OS's because certain tools aren't available on certain ones. However, I run a web server on my Ubuntu OS, and usually keep that OS running unless I truly need to take down the machine for 10 minutes.

If I reboot the machine too many times within an hour, the timeout feature seems to be automatically disabled, and GRUB will just sit at the OS selection screen all day. This is a massive inconvenience if I have to remotely log into the Ubuntu machine a few times for remote maintenance, and it gets stuck at GRUB when it reboots, since I have to be at the physical machine in order to get an OS started. Is this a bug or feature of GRUB, and if so, how can I disable it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have never experienced this issue with GRUB, and I have a dual-booted laptop that I often switch between Ubuntu (default in 10 s), and Windows 8.1.

No selection will be made if any key presses occur, so a stray key press can interrupt the automatic selection without booting to an OS.